# EF CTP4 - create tables, but not drop DB

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

I have a single hosted SQL Server DB and I don't have permissions to drop it. How do I make EF create tables from my domain classes? RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges and AlwaysRecreateDatabase try to drop DB, CreateDatabaseOnlyIfNotExists doesn't create the tables.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*CreateDatabaseOnlyIfNotExists* is the *default* strategy. It means you don't need to even set it through the Database.SetInitializer. EF Code First will check the database and if couldn't find one with the same name as your context's fully qualified name, it will create one for you.

Comment: CreateDatabaseOnlyIfNotExists throws an exception if the DB already exists, but the tables are not there.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If the database is there - be it empty or full of tables - EF will do nothing and just throw an exception. You need to manually drop your database before running your app.

Comment: So go ahead and fix it: create all the tables and everything and make sure that it exactly matches your object model, so that EF will work with it without throwing an exception.

Comment: Haha, so every time I change my model go and edit the DB. I've started using a local DB for development and created a TLS package to sync the changes, but it's still a time waste.

Comment: As of CTP4, EF is *NOT* capable to alter your database, it either recreates it or you are responsible to change it. For now you have to choose either of these workflows for your development until the RTW version releases which will come with a *Database Migration* feature.